# View resizes to full screen after app becomes active

Tags: iphone, ios

**My situation:**

I have a text input field at the bottom of my view (the outermost view does not scroll). When someone focuses the input, I shrink the view to accomodate the keyboard (specifically, I subtract the height of the keyboard and animate the view to a new height).

**My problem:**

Whenever something takes focus away from my ViewController and returns it soon after (e.g. a push notification or someone hitting the home button and coming back to the app later), the view seems to automatically resize so that the text input is back at the bottom of the screen, *but* the keyboard remains showing.

**What I want:**

I want the view to maintain the size it had before the app regained focus. The keyboard should remain showing and the text input show display above it, not move back down to the bottom of the screen behind the keyboard.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or what I need to do to get this behavior?

Comment: Instead of shrinking your view would it be possible to move your view up along the y axis?

Comment: Does your UITextfieldDelegate get sent the –textFieldDidBeginEditing: message after it regains focus?

Comment: I don't get a textFieldDidBeginEditing message after the app regains focus (I *do* get it when I first tap the input, which is expected). When the app regains focus, the text input doesn't actually lose focus - if I type on the keyboard, I can see the autocomplete show up

Comment: @bbarnhart If I change the y coordinate instead of height, then the scrolling of my inner views becomes messed up (scrollbar displays incorrectly and cannot scroll up to view the top of the display

Comment: Do -resignFirstResponder and -becomeFirstResponder get fired when the push notification appears/disappears?

Comment: The input never actually resigns its firstResponder state (hence why the keyboard remains visible and if you type, it appears in the input box). The problem is that the view is just resized but I can't tell why. The issue also happen when leaving/returning to the app (not just with a push notif)

Comment: In that case -applicationWillEnterForeground: or -applicationDidBecomeActive: may be what you are looking for. At the very least you should be able to get it to work properly when the app closes or opens. On the other hand, you may prefer deactivating the keyboard when the app enters the background in -applicationWillResignActive:

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

```
    static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
    static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
    static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
    static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
    static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;



   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

     CGRect textFieldRect =     [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];

    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];


        CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
        CGFloat numerator =
        midline - viewRect.origin.y
        - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
        CGFloat denominator =
        (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
        * viewRect.size.height;
        CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;


        if (heightFraction < 0.0)
        {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
        }
        else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
        {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
        }



        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);



        CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

        [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }



 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```